# Set ACL with Name Variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

I currently have the below code to set an ACL permissions on a folder.

```
$Acl = Get-Acl $TextBox2.text

$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domainname\$NameofgroupLCLM", "Modify", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")

$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl $TextBox2.text $Acl
```

`$Textbox2.text` has the network path of the folder in. I am currently trying to set it to the group stored in the variable `$nameofgrouplclM` but I get an error:

```
Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity
references could not be translated."
At line:177 char:2
+ $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException
```

If I have "domainname\groupexample" in the code with no variable it goes through fine. I was wondering how I would use a variable in this bit of code?

Comment: Looks fine, the error is about mapping to security IDs? The most likely error is that it cannot find the group, whether that's because the group name isn't the groups SamAccountName or there's a typo in the variable.

Comment: The format is potentially fine, but the group name is not (or you wouldn't see that error). Groups can be confusing because they have more than one name field. Try `Get-ADGroup yourGroup -Properties SamAccountName | Select SamAccountName`. Is that the value you're using?

Comment: Found out my variable, set with another button doesn't hold it's value when the 2nd button is pressed. Is this something you would expect? Can you set permenant variables as well?

Comment: It really depends how you've implemented the button and the interface the button effects. I would expect it to, but I say that only knowing what I might do.

Comment: What is the actual value of `$NameofgroupLCLM`? Check the output of `Get-Member -InputObject $NameofgroupLCLM`.